# Oracle 19c won't install

Tags: oracle-database

Kind of a mess here. Did two successful successive installs of Oracle 19c database and now no Oracle database will install on my Windows 10 Pro machine. Found that installing Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2019 somehow wiped out my previously working Oracle Database install. After I installed Oracle Developer Tools, sqlplus stopped working. Sql Developer wouldn't connect, and c# programs that previously read the local Oracle wouldn't work. One install/uninstall (19c has only a manual uninstall) cycle was successful but now Oracle 19c won't install at all. It asks to be admin and you see a brief flicker of the install gui, and then it stops. Quits so fast I'm not sure there's a log file anywhere. Got so desperate I tried Oracle 18c but that fails quickly too. Any reset possible short of reinstalling Windows 10?

Comment: Oracle installer should be creating a log, can you provide the relevant information from you last attempt?  Edit your question instead of submitting information from a log in a comment

Answer (score 0):

ok, made a lot of progress here.  there are 2 questions:

1. why was other oracle software wiping out the 19c db install
2. why would an oracle 19c download not install, and fail quickly with no message

answer to one: the default oracle 19c db install points at the directory (this is for the actual database location) from which the install sofware is running.   If you don't change the install location, other oracle software downloads (oracle client, oracle developer tools) will clobber your database.   I changed the database install location to c:\app\Oracle .
answer to two:  the new win10 treats the download directory differently.  win10 doesn't just show a static list of whatever folders are in your download directory, it shows kind of a history of downloads you have made.  Although I don't see the oracle 19c download earlier in my downloads, one 19c download I did made a (1) (identical name, same directory location) entry.   when I tried to run the 19c db install it failed immediately with no log error that I could find.   I had stashed the 19c db install elsewhere on my machine earlier and when I ran that install, it installed oracle 19c db.